# How can we create an Index on MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongodb-query

I want to create an Index on Mongo database for performance perspective, so could you please help me how I can do it?

Your help will be appreciated here.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If you want to index on field `email` on `users` collection:

```
db.users.createIndex({"email":1}, {background:true})
```

Before applying indexing in mongodb collections you need to understand the following aspects of indexing:

**Indexing strategy:**

- Check your application for what type of queries does it send to mongodb.
- List down all such possible queries.
- Based on the number of operations, type of operations define [index type](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/#index-types)
- Choose the correct type of indexes for application needs. Type can be single index, compound index, partial index, TTL index and so on
- Do your queries involve the sort operations? Follow this [guide on indexing for operations with sort](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/#use-indexes-to-sort-query-results).
- The more detailed guide on indexing strategy [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/applications/indexes/#indexing-strategies).

**Test your indexes:**

- Once you have the list of indexes to be applied, test your indexes performance using [explain](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/#cursor-explain).
- Generate a sample application calls on your database and [enable profiler](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/#database-profiler) (in dev or stag) to check how your indexes are performing.

**How to index:**

- [Create indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/#db-collection-createindex) in the background. It will make sure that the create index operation does not block the other operations.
- Depending on your data size, if the indexes to be created on large collections, consider doing it in low traffic hours. Or in a scheduled maintenance window
- You may need to consider [building rolling index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/build-indexes-on-replica-sets/#build-indexes-on-replica-sets) in certain use cases to minimize the impact of indexing.

**Keep track of indexes you create:**

- Document your indexes. This may include when you have created those indexes, why and so on.

**Measure your index usage stats in production:**

- Once you have applied these indexes in production, in a week or two check usage [stas](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexStats/#indexstats-aggregation) of your indexes to check whether they're really being used
- Consider dropping the indexes if they're not used at all.

**Caution:**

- Indexes add [performance penalty](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/write-performance/#indexes) for write operations. Design and apply indexes which are must for your application.

Answer (score 13):

The basic syntax is:

`db.collection.createIndex(keys, options)`

So, for example:

`$ db.users.createIndex({"username" : 1})`

See [MongoDB Indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/) for the full details.